# Deleting a blog post leaves related .png files in Photos list

Tags: list, blog, delete, image

I used the blog template when creating a new subsite within mysites and in the process an associated list called Photos got created.

While this has worked well, I've noticed that when I delete a blog post that contained some images (filetype is .png), the images that were part of the blog post content remain behind.

Is there a setting that results in something like "delete any images for the blog post when the blog item is deleted"?

This is Sharepoint 2010 Server Enterprise Edition SP1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the OOTB functionality, probably based on the thought that you might use the same pictures in more than one place, even in other places than a blog post.

If that is the case, and SharePoint just deletes the image on post deletion, you would get corrupt image links in all other places referencing that particular image file.

You could write an ItemDeleting Event Receiver that parses the body of the blog post for image links and then removes them from their resp. libraries before the blog post is deleted.